# information needed on checking the google sign in and showing verification URL:

Tags: google-signin

I am going through the https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices and i 
am trying to get the code and verification URL as mentioned in the link using my CLIENT_ID which i have got from the cloud platform. 
curl -d "client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=email profile" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code

I am getting the below error:
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Invalid client type."
}
I am not getting the user_code and verification_url as a response.
Am I missing something?

Comment: curl -d "client_id=XXX.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code -vvv
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2019 07:07:26 GMT
< Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Invalid client type."
* Connection #0 to host accounts.google.com left intact
}

Comment: I have learned that the oAuth2 client id created should be of other type as mentioned. After creating the client id using the others, the google signin and showning verification URL worked as expected.